# When should I release dictionary created by [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

Let's say I created an NSMutableDictionary object by using the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

When should I release this object? Do I call retain when passing it to other methods?

Comment: It's already autoreleased. Have you read Apple's docs on memory management?

Comment: You may want to edit your question again Chris... `dictionary` is declared as a `NSDictionary` while you are calling the mutable `NSMutableDictionary` method.  If you don't get a compiler error, you will at least get a warning.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary is a subclass of NSDictionary. I am just using this snippet as an example. I am not using it this way.

Comment: Then you'd want to edit your question (both the title and the code snippet) to say `NSMutableDictionary`.  At least it'd make things clear, as opposed to setting off my "what the ??" alarms in my head.

Comment: I guess I was just trying to get my point across rather than worrying about what I can do with created object. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) you don't need to release an autoreleased object (which is the `NSDictionary` object returned by the `dictionary` method...)

2) if you're using ARC, you don't need to even care about retaining or releasing.